# Insert a 0x00 byte in a C program argument using perl

Tags: bash

I'm reading Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson. In chapter 0x330 he uses perl to insert the same memory address a few times in the argument of a program.

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./auth_overflow2 $(perl -e 'print "\xbf\x84\x04\x08"x10')
```

My addresses are of 64 bits instead of 32, so I guess I only have to add the corresponding extra bytes. The address I want to use is 0x000000001266, so I tried this:

```
./auth_overflow $(perl -e 'print "\x66\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"x10')
```

But I get this warning "bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input" and I don't get the result I'm expecting. What does the warning mean? Bash removes all the 0x00 bytes and the program argument end with the 0x66 and 0x12 bytes only? How can I add a 0x00 byte using perl then?

Comment: This is not related to Perl. Arguments to programs are passed as C-style strings and the null byte terminates them; there's no way how to include a null byte to an argument (you can insert it to output, though). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017/13792

Comment: Command line arguments are passed as C strings, so they are terminated by null bytes. But they are *typically* laid out in memory sequentially. So you may be able to append null bytes by passing additional empty arguments. Never tried this though – when I do these kinds of exploit demos I prefer 32 bit for simplicity, or use a test driver that doesn't rely on command line args.

Comment: I don't know this book. If you have the source and can compile `auth_overflow`, you could have it ignore the final byte of the argument and pass any non-zero character as the last one to work around this limitation.

Comment: Or you can let the command line arguments be string (i.e. `'\x66\x12\x00'`) and convert them in `auth_overflow`

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! Well, then I guess the exploit is not possible if the address has one or more null bytes. Your solutions imply modifying the program, but then it would be pointless because I don't think there are many  programs who convert a string containing hexadecimal values, or pass all non-zero characters as the last ones. But again, thanks anyway!

@amon you mention that you prefer 32 bits to do these types of exploits. Can I change the address length somehow, even though the architecture of my computer is 64 bits? Maybe the 32 bit address will not contain null bytes

Comment: @MateuSaiós I meant that for *learning* about exploits, using simplifications like a 32-bit architecture can be helpful. If you're learning e.g. about stack overflows, fighting with command line arguments is a distraction and you'd instead build an example program that fits your use case. If you want to learn to attack a program through its command line arguments, such a simplification would of course be impossible. Similarly, such simplifications can't be used if you want to exploit an existing program.